Ordered 4-tuples with sum less than $k$
Consider the sum
$$
\begin{align}
S=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=n+i+j}^\infty\:C(i,j,n,k)\cdot\epsilon^k
\end{align}
$$
with some generic, non-symmetric coefficients $C(i,j,n,k)$. We'd like to factor out the powers of $\epsilon$, i.e to write
\begin{align}
S=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\epsilon^k\cdot\Big[\cdots \Big]_k
\end{align}
The $\Big[\cdots \Big]_k$ seems to be the sum of all the $C(i,j,n,k)$ where $i+j+n\leq k$; is there a nice or general form to write this quantity ?

@confused_wallet No, not really. Why do you think so ?

Disregard my first comment, you're correct -- I suppose one could write $\Big[\cdots \Big]k = \sum{i=0}^k \sum_{j=0}^{k-i}\sum_{n=0}^{k-i-j} C(i,j,n,k)$. There should also be recursive formulas to aid in the computation of $\Big[\cdots \Big]k$ once $\Big[\cdots \Big]{k-1}$ has been calculated. What sort of general form are you hoping for?

@confused_wallet One in which all the remaining three sums are independent, meaning, where each index starts from $0$ or some number and runs to $\infty$ independently of other indexes. In any case, the most simplified form.
